# setImageResource не меняет src

Tags: android, xml, android-imageview, android-constraintlayout

```
public class BubbleSortActivity extends SortActivity{


    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    Button shuffleButton;
    List<Integer> ID;
    List<Integer> DRAWABLE;
    List<Integer> YELLOW_DRAWABLE;
    List<Integer> RED_DRAWABLE;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sort);
        shuffleButton = findViewById(R.id.shuffle);
        constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        ID = Arrays.asList(0, R.id.num1,R.id.num2,R.id.num3,R.id.num4,R.id.num5,R.id.num6,R.id.num7,R.id.num8,R.id.num9);
        DRAWABLE = Arrays.asList(0,R.drawable.icons8_1_24,R.drawable.icons8_2_24,R.drawable.icons8_3_24,R.drawable.icons8_4_24,R.drawable.icons8_5_24,
                R.drawable.icons8_6_24,R.drawable.icons8_7_24,R.drawable.icons8_8_24,R.drawable.icons8_9_24);
        RED_DRAWABLE = Arrays.asList(0,R.drawable.icons8_1_24_red,R.drawable.icons8_2_24_red,R.drawable.icons8_3_24_red,R.drawable.icons8_4_24_red,R.drawable.icons8_5_24_red,
                R.drawable.icons8_6_24_red,R.drawable.icons8_7_24_red,R.drawable.icons8_8_24_red,R.drawable.icons8_9_24_red);
        YELLOW_DRAWABLE = Arrays.asList(0,R.drawable.icons8_1_24_yellow,R.drawable.icons8_2_24_yellow,R.drawable.icons8_3_24_yellow,R.drawable.icons8_4_24_yellow,R.drawable.icons8_5_24_yellow,
                R.drawable.icons8_6_24_yellow,R.drawable.icons8_7_24_yellow,R.drawable.icons8_8_24_yellow,R.drawable.icons8_9_24_yellow);
        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);

        shuffleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                check();
            }
        });

    }
boolean check()
    {
        ImageView view1 = findViewById(ID.get(1));
        ImageView view2 = findViewById(ID.get(2));
        view1.setImageResource(YELLOW_DRAWABLE.get(1));
        view2.setImageResource(YELLOW_DRAWABLE.get(2));
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        view1.setImageResource(DRAWABLE.get(1));
        view2.setImageResource(DRAWABLE.get(2));
        return true;
    }
}
public abstract class SortActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int[] list = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    ArrayList<ImageView> viewList;
    void shuffleArray(int[] ar)
    {
        // If running on Java 6 or older, use `new Random()` on RHS here
        Random rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
        for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
            // Simple swap
            int a = ar[index];
            ar[index] = ar[i];
            ar[i] = a;
        }
    }
    void sort(int[] arr)
    {

    }
}
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/num9"
    style="@style/ArrayElement"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/mainLayout"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/num8"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:src="@drawable/icons8_9_24" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не меняются src в ImageViews... (Должны по нажатию на Перемешать) В чем может быть ошибка???? (Слушатель работает, проблема не в этом)

Comment: Когда главный поток должен был рисовать жёлтые картинки - он спал (`Thread.sleep(2000);`). А когда проснулся - уже надо менять назад. Нельзя усыплять главный поток. Читайте про `Handler` - такие задачи решают с его помощью.

Comment: спасибо, учту, с handlerом заработало